# Bundle Identifier in Expo IOS

Tags: ios, expo, bundle

The bundle identifier for my iOS expo app is just "calendar". But I think it has to be "com.company.calendar" or something like this. Please guide.

Answer (score 6):

Have you configured `expo.ios.bundleIdentifier` in app.json or app.config.js?
Its value has to be "com.company.calendar".
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/config/app/#bundleidentifier

Answer (score 0):

In app.json add bundleIdentifier Json property as such:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "shopping-list",
    "slug": "shopping-list",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.shoppingList"
    },
   }
```